# How to filter lines passed through a pipe?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I've got a command `foo` that outputs a list of filenames:

```
$ foo
file1.a
file2.b
file3.a
```

And a command `bar` that accepts the names of `.a` files as arguments and does some processing:

```
$ bar file1.a file3.a
Great success!
$ bar file2.b
FAILURE
```

I'd like to combine the two with a pipe like `foo | xargs bar`, but I need to filter out all filenames that don't end in `.a`. How can I do this? Ideally I want something simple I can stick between the two commands in a pipe, like `foo | filter-lines ".a" | xargs bar`.

Comment: You should read up on the 'text processing' tag, and learn some or all of the following tools: `grep`, `sed`, `awk`; and also `cut`, `paste`, `join`.  For the postgraduate text-processing tool you can learn Perl, but in 99% of cases you can accomplish everything you want with a simple `grep` or `sed` one-liner.

Comment: how is it even possible to know about something relatively obscure like `xargs` but not `grep` or `sed`?

Comment: @cas Completely forgot that grep would view the standard input as a file rather than checking each file's contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `grep` to grab all files within `foo` that end with `.a`.

`foo | grep "\.a$" | xargs -d'\n' -r bar`

Comment: Hmm,   wouldn't  `grep \\.a$` be better?  Oh, I see someone else got there first

Comment: +1. you should use `xargs -d'\n' bar` for safety, in case any filenames have spaces or other annoying characters in them.  If you're using GNU `xargs`, you should also use `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` so that `xargs` doesn't run `bar` if the input is empty:   `xargs -d'\n' -r bar`

Comment: @cas - Thank you for the suggestions. I have edited the answer.

Comment: if `foo` produced NUL-separated output, you could use `xargs -0r`  (and `grep -z`) and it would work even with filenames that have embedded newlines...but you have to work with what you get.